# Запрос для фиксирования приходов и уходов сотрудников (ClickHouse)

Tags: clickhouse, powerbi

Всем добрый день/вечер!
Я написала запрос, скрипт ниже, не могу никак додуматься, как его допилить. Буду максимально благодарна любой помощи, так как являюсь полным новичком в этом. (Подходящих форумов не нашла)

Скрипт необходим для последующей визуализации, график должен отобразить время приходов на работу и уходов с работы конкретного сотрудника за месяц (пишу для общего понимания)

Мне необходимо добавить следующее:

1. поле Arrivals (Приходы), которое показывают самое минимальное время для каждого пользователя за день с условием, что поле Side = "Вход".
2. также поле Departures (Уходы), которое показывают максимальное время для каждого пользователя за день с условием, что поле Side = "Выход". Но есть нюанс, в случае, если Source у пользователя  = "Telegram"  , то у него в принципе зафиксирован только приход, как и в прошлой ситуации, а поле Departures необходимо рассчитывать, как  Arrivals + 10 часов).

```
-- Данные для графика приходы и уходы
SELECT 
  d.id,
  d.ufUser,
  toDate(ufDate, 'Asia/Novosibirsk') AS DAYS, 
  dateName('hour', ufDate, 'Asia/Novosibirsk') AS HOURS, 
  arrayStringConcat(mapValues(d.ufSide), ', ') as Side,
  arrayStringConcat(mapValues(d.ufOffice), ', ') as Office,
  arrayStringConcat(mapValues(d.ufSource), ', ') as Source,
  formatDateTime(toTime(ufDate, 'Asia/Novosibirsk'), '%T') as Time,
  User.LAST_NAME || ' ' || User.NAME || ' ' || User.SECOND_NAME as user_name
FROM db.Dom d FINAL
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT 
    ID,
    LAST_NAME,
    NAME,
    SECOND_NAME
   FROM db.user FINAL
   ) AS User ON d.ufUser = User.ID
 WHERE  d.ufUser != 0 AND isNotNull(user_name)
```